# Add directives to component selector when it is declared - Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular2-directives, angular-components

I am learning Angular and am creating components dynamically on the click of a button. I am trying to use Angular Material's drag and drop feature to drag these created components to sort them. I have the following code in my base component html:

```
<div cdkDropList style="margin: 20px" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div #container></div>
</div>
```

And the Typescript code has the following code:

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef})
  container: ViewContainerRef;

const childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomComponent);
const component = this.container.createComponent(childComponent);
```

So far, I have managed to create components dynamically, and have managed to get them as child of div with the directive "cdkDropList".

What I am not able to do is get the components created with the cdkDrag directive declared in its element name. For eg:

```
<app-CustomComponent cdkDrag>
```

I am looking into @HostBinding and can create components with attributes. Not able to figure out how to use it to declare directives. I am sure I am missing something obvious, but so far I am stuck. Please help.

Comment: You are not missing anything. This is simply not possible. You should either add it to the parent component, or on the first element in the component's template

Comment: Oh thats disappointing. I had tried to add it to the first element in the component template, and it simply doesnt work. Maybe Angular Material needs the directive declared on the immediate child of the div with directive "cdkDropList", but I am not sure. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Yes, another downside, cdkDropList and cdkDrag need to be in the same template. Maybe you can do something in the constructor of the child (which has the cdkDrag), by injecting the CdkDropList, and adding the cdkDrag manually, but I'm pretty sure that won't work, but it's worth to try

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it to work as follows in my following question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56108285/angular-7-add-drag-and-drop-behaviour-to-dynamically-created-components