# Angular 7 - Add drag and drop behaviour to dynamically created components

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drag-and-drop, angular-components

This is in continuation of the previous question I asked on SO:
[Add directives to component selector when it is declared - Angular 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56072516/add-directives-to-component-selector-when-it-is-declared-angular-7)

I am dynamically creating components on a button click. The components are displayed one below another in a list like manner. I want to introduce drag-drop behaviour so that the user can rearrange the components after creating them.

In the previous question, I tried using Angular-Material, but realised it might not be possible to use it for components, due to the issue of adding "cdkDrag" directive to the component's selector tag, and the fact that the cdkDropList and cdkDrag might need to be in the same template.

I have a div as such in the template:

```
<div cdkDropList style="margin: 20px" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div #container></div>
</div>
```

And, I am creating custom components as follows:

```
@ViewChild('container', {read: ViewContainerRef})
  container: ViewContainerRef;

const childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomComponent);
const component = this.container.createComponent(childComponent);
```

This works fine. Is it possible at all to create draggable dynamically created components?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

While this works fine with one single type of component, if you need to use different dynamic types of components, read Chaitanya Bangera's comment down below!

## Original Comment

Should work with something like this (CmpComponent would be your component that you want to insert):

```js
  components: CmpComponent[];

const childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomComponent);
this.components.push(childComponent);


drop(event: CdkDragDrop<CmpComponent[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.components, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

```html
<div cdkDropList style="margin: 20px" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <div cdkDrag *ngFor="let cmp of components">
        <app-cmp></app-cmp>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am having a look, although I feel I might run into difficulty as the user can create one of several available components dynamically. Its like a list of widgets that the user can click and create, so <app-cmp> in the template might not work.
Edit: I will try it for a single component though, to check if the approach works.

Comment: I got it to work using your code as base and using ng-container instead of the component selectorfor *ngFor and it finally works. I am going to mark your answer as accepted since it works for a single template. I have added my answer below that works for different components.

Comment: @ChaitanyaBangera Glad it worked! I updated my answer so that people with the same problem find your comment more easily.

Comment: @ChaitanyaBangera can you tell me pls how you worked with component parameters in this way?
I mean, do you use Inputs/Outputs with dynamically generated values or is there some way to access to component instance? Have the same problem as yours, and don't have an idea what to do with component params.

Answer (score 3):

I'm done with this problem by generating components dynamically with createComponent method and processing move by ViewComponentRef method:

**container.component.html**

```
<div cdkDropList (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ng-container #cmpContainer></ng-container>
</div>
```

**container.component.ts**

```
import {CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray} from "@angular/cdk/drag-drop";
import {DynamicComponent} from './dynamic.component.ts';

@ViewChild('cmpContainer', {static: true, read: ViewContainerRef}) cmpContainer: ViewContainerRef;
components: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent>[] = [];

addComponent() {
    const factory = this.cfr.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicComponent);
    const component: ComponentRef<DynamicComponent> = this.cmpContainer.createComponent(factory);
    this.components.push(component);
}

drop(event: CdkDragDrop<DynamicComponent[]>) {
    this.cmpContainer.move(this.components[event.previousIndex].hostView, event.currentIndex);
    moveItemInArray(this.components, prevIndex, currentIndex);
}
```

**dynamic.component.html**

```
<div cdkDrag>
    <div cdkDragHandle></div>
</div>
```

- In this case, you can access component instance directly through the components array.

Answer (score 2):

Finally got it to work, thanks to the reply from MauriceNino. I am going to mark Maurice's answer as accepted, since their solution works fine for a single component.

While getting Maurice's solution to work for multiple components, I came across this magical concept called ng-container! What a life-saver!! My solution is as follows:

```
components=[];

const childComponent = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(CustomComponent);
this.components.push(childComponent);


drop(event: CdkDragDrop<CmpComponent[]>) {
  moveItemInArray(this.components, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
}
```

Now for the template:

```
<div cdkDropList class="example-list" style="margin: 20px" (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let cmp of components">
        <ng-container *ngIf="cmp.componentType.name=='Component1'">
            <app-Component1 cdkDrag></app-Component1>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="cmp.componentType.name=='Component2'">
            <app-Component2 cdkDrag></app-Component2>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-container *ngIf="cmp.componentType.name=='Component3'">
            <app-Component3 cdkDrag></app-Component3>
        </ng-container>

    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Finally, after a week of searching, it finally works!
Thank you!

Comment: drop(event: CdkDragDrop<CmpComponent[]>) can you please tell me CMpCOmponet[] is refer to?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create `div` around every `ng-container` and set `cdkDrag` attribute on it.

Answer (score 0):

Requirement was to create draggable editable Row(s). User can add/delete row.

Here to apply cdk drag (with  cdkdraglist directive ) directive to all the dynamically created elements. so this cdk drag and drop will work. but angular is not allowing runtime addition of directive to am element in template. concluding that ,to achive this feature we have to take support in of a grid framework(like ag-grid).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).